# Expo Location, Expo Task Manager with Context API react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-context

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  authenticationService,
  getUserProfileService,
} from '../services/user-service';
import { getDonationHistory } from '../services/donation-service';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';

const UserInfoContext = createContext();

const UserInfoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState({
    donorId: '',
    icNo: '',
    fName: '',
    lName: '',
    bloodType: '',
  });
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({ latitude: '', longitude: '' });

  let updateLocation = (loc) => {
    setLocation(loc);
  };

  console.log(location);

  const sendBackgroundLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('LocationUpdate', {
          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
          timeInterval: 10000,
          distanceInterval: 1,
          foregroundService: {
            notificationTitle: 'Live Tracker',
            notificationBody: 'Live Tracker is on.',
          },
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const _requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status == 'granted') {
        let { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status == 'granted') {
        } else {
          console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
      }
    })();
  };

  sendBackgroundLocation();

  const getUserProfile = () => {
    return userProfile;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await _requestLocationPermission())();
    retrieveAuthTokens();
    retrieveUserProfile();
  });

  let retrieveAuthTokens = async () => {
    try {
      const authTokens = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authTokens');
      authTokens ? setIsLoggedIn(true) : setIsLoggedIn(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  let retrieveUserProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const userProfile = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('userProfile'));
      userProfile
        ? setUserProfile({
            donorId: userProfile.donorId,
            icNo: userProfile.appUser.username,
            fName: userProfile.fName,
            lName: userProfile.lName,
            bloodType: userProfile.bloodType,
          })
        : null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  let loginUser = (values) => {
    authenticationService(values)
      .then(async (data) => {
        if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
          const tokens = data.data;
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(tokens));
          getProfile(values.icNo);
          getHistories(userProfile.donorId);
          setErrorMessage(null);
        } else {
          setErrorMessage('Wrong email/password!');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };

  let logoutUser = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.clear().then(console.log('clear'));
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  getProfile = (icNo) => {
    getUserProfileService(icNo)
      .then(async (res) => {
        if (res !== undefined && res !== null) {
          const profile = res.data;
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('userProfile', JSON.stringify(profile));
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };

  const getHistories = (userId) => {
    getDonationHistory(userId)
      .then(async (res) => {
        if (res !== undefined && res !== null) {
          const historyData = res.data;
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'donationHistories',
            JSON.stringify(historyData)
          );
        } else {
          console.log('no data');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
  };

  let contextData = {
    loginUser: loginUser,
    logoutUser: logoutUser,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    userProfile: userProfile,
    getHistories: getHistories,
  };

  return (
    <UserInfoContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {children}
    </UserInfoContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useUserInfo = () => useContext(UserInfoContext);

export default UserInfoProvider;

function myTask() {
  try {
    const backendData = 'Simulated fetch ' + Math.random();
    return backendData
      ? BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData
      : BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NoData;
  } catch (err) {
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;
  }
}

async function initBackgroundFetch(taskName, interval = 60 * 15) {
  try {
    if (!TaskManager.isTaskDefined(taskName)) {
      TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, ({ data, error }) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Error bg', error);
          return;
        }
        if (data) {
          const { locations } = data;
          console.log(
            locations[0].coords.latitude,
            locations[0].coords.longitude
          );

          //-----------------doesnt work ----------------------------
          UserInfoProvider.updateLocation({
            latitude: locations[0].coords.latitude,
            longitude: locations[0].coords.longitude,
          });
          //-----------------doesnt work ----------------------------
        }
      });
    }
    const options = {
      minimumInterval: interval, // in seconds
    };
    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName, options);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('registerTaskAsync() failed:', err);
  }
}

initBackgroundFetch('LocationUpdate', 5);
```

I'm trying to update the location state in the UserInfoProvider and this location info will be sent to the firestore along with the userprofile details retrieved in this provider.

However, it seems that i cant access the

> UserInfoProvider.updateLocation()

outside the UserInfoProvider component.

Is there anyway I can get both the userprofile info and the location info retrieved from background task together and send them to firestore?

At the moment, only the

> console.log(
> locations[0].coords.latitude,
> locations[0].coords.longitude
> );

in the background task seems to be working.

Error I got:

> TaskManager: Task "LocationUpdate" failed:, [TypeError: undefined is
> not a function (near '...UserInfoProvider.updateLocation...')]      at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in
> registerError at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in
> console.error at
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error at node_modules\expo-task-manager\build\TaskManager.js:143:16 in
> eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1 at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:190:16 in
> PromiseImpl$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6
> in tryCallTwo at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11
> in Promise at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:15 in
> callInvokeWithMethodAndArg at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:212:38 in enqueue at
> node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:239:8 in exports.async at
> node_modules\expo-task-manager\build\TaskManager.js:133:57 in
> eventEmitter.addListener$argument_1 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4
> in __callFunction at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6
> in __guard$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10
> in __guard at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4
> in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing `UserInfoProvider` context value:

```
let contextData = {
    loginUser: loginUser,
    logoutUser: logoutUser,
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    userProfile: userProfile,
    getHistories: getHistories,
  };
```

`updateLocation` function not available and you can't access.

You need to use `useUserInfo` to consume `UserInfoProvider` value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But i have used another approach which is storing the location values inside the AsyncStorage and retrieve them later on to pass it to the firestore in my background task.  Can you tell whether this approach is acceptable? This is my first react native project, thats why i have some doubts...

Comment: That's fine as you can access stored value globally.